# How to save normalized images for ImageDataGenerator()

Tags: python, image-processing

I want to train a [CSRNet](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1802.10062.pdf) model. The recommendation here is to normalize each image with respect to the weights of the original training of VGG16.

I am iterating all my images applying:

```
im = im/255.0
im[:,:,0]=(im[:,:,0]-0.485)/0.229
im[:,:,1]=(im[:,:,1]-0.456)/0.224
im[:,:,2]=(im[:,:,2]-0.406)/0.225
```

Since my data is too large to fit in memory and I want to use augmentations, I am saving all images in a directory for an  ImageDataGenerator(). I have tried pickling (oops) them at first and got an error that the generator does not recognize them as images (not surprising).

The problem is that none of these images are of type `uint8`. If I will try and save them using PIL or any other method, the modules require a `uint8` type. However, if I convert to uint8 I lose my standardization.

I can think of one method to go around this, applying the normalization after the augmentations. I can do this using the `preprocessing_function` parameter, however, this will be very time-consuming. Is there another way to go about this?

Comment: Are you sure that it is time consuming compared to other operations ?

Comment: I am sure that it is time-consuming to normalize each image in each iteration over normalizing them once at the beginning, yes.  I am asking if there is a way around it.

Comment: What is the percentage of overhead ?

Comment: I don't understand your environment or your objective, but you seem to be concerned about images being stored as `uint8` when you would prefer them to be floating point. If so, maybe you could store as TIFF, or as PFM, both of which can store floats.